# Is Microsoft Graph API available for Microsoft Teams usage report

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

There is Teams usage report, Teams user activity report, Teams device usage report available in Microsoft Teams admin center.
In Microsoft Teams admin center -> Analytics & reports > Usage reports
Below is the link to the docs -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoftteams/teams-analytics-and-reports/teams-usage-report

Is there any Microsoft graph API available for Microsoft Teams usage report? We need data which are shown in Teams usage report.

APIs are available for Teams user activity report, Teams device usage report but not for teams usage.

Answer (score 0):

We have not yet exposed the Teams usage reports on the MS graph and it's likely not going to be available in the near term. The feedback so far has been that 7 / 28 days window is not sufficient to gather meaningful insights and hence we are considering an update across various reporting scenarios where we are able to satisfy a longer duration and related mechanics. We hope to address this collectively in the future. Stay Tuned.